# Why is $E[g(X,\beta)^T\ g(X,\beta)]$ derived to $\beta$ equals $E[g'(X,\beta)\ g(X,\beta)]$? Why no product rule in deriving?

Tags: derivatives, expectation, self-learning, linear-regression

I try to follow the analytical derivation of linear regression in *The Elements of statistical learning* (Friedman, Tibshirani, Hastie), where they use a regression function

$$f(x) = x^T\beta $$
and want to derive the set of regression coefficients $\beta$, such that the Expected Prediction Error EPE for a random input variable $X\in\mathbb{R}^p$ and a random output variable $Y\in\mathbb{R}$ gets minimal.

The book does not show a line of thought. I found [this Question on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/89251/82389) which states the following transformations: (corrected according to remarks in the [answer there](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/89252/82389))

> $$ EPE(f) = E\left[(Y-f(X))^2\right] = E\left[(Y-X^T\beta)^T(Y-X^T\beta)\right] $$
>   $$ \frac{\partial{EPE(f)}}{\partial \beta} = E\left[X(Y-X^T\beta)\right]$$

I do not understand the second line. It looks like only the first factor $(Y-X^T\beta)$ must be derived and the second one stays unchanged.

Shortening $g(X):=Y-X^T\beta$ and $g'(X)=\partial g/\partial \beta = X^T$ and therefore

$$EPE = E[g(X)^Tg(X)]$$

using the product rule I would have expected something like

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial{EPE}}{\partial \beta} 
   &= E\left[ g'(X)^Tg(X)+g(X)^Tg'(X)          \right] \\
   &= E\left[ X(Y-X^T\beta)+(Y-X^T\beta)^T X^T \right]
\end{align}

Is this an error in the question at Cross Validated or does it result from some rule about differentiating inside an Expectation Value which I do not know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $g(X):=Y-X^T\beta$ is a scalar so $\frac\partial{\partial\beta}g(X)$ and $\frac\partial{\partial\beta}[g(X)^T]$ are both equal to $-X$, and notice that the two terms $X(Y-X^T\beta)$ and $(Y-X^T\beta)^T X$ are in fact the same.  The Cross Validated derivation is correct, it's just missing a factor of $2$ (actually $-2$).

More directly, you can differentiate using the chain rule:
$$\frac\partial{\partial\beta}(Y-X^T\beta)^2=2(Y-X^T\beta)\frac\partial{\partial\beta}(Y-X^T\beta)=2(Y-X^T\beta)(-X).$$

Comment: This answer builds a bridge to the [Solution manual by Weatherwax and Epstein](http://www.waxworksmath.com/Authors/G_M/Hastie/hastie.html), which follow the same path! I do not yet understand, however, why $\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}[g(X)]=-X$ and not $-X^T$? Can you help me out there once again?

Comment: @akraf $Y-X^T\beta=Y-\sum X_k\beta_k$. Differentiating this with respect to $\beta_i$ gives $-X_i$. So assemble these into a column vector and you get $-X$. The convention that FTH are using is that the derivative of a scalar function with respect to a column vector is a *column* vector, sometimes known as the 'denominator-layout' notation. The alternative convention is to put the derivative in a *row* vector $-X^T$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus for details on denominator-layout vs numerator-layout. Note that identities about derivatives will differ for these two layouts.

Comment: Now it makes sense! Thanks for teaching me this!